# How to retrieve site root url?

Tags: c#, asp.net, url

I need to get the url of the site so that I render a user control on only the main page. I need to check for http://foo.com, http://www.foo.com, and foo.com. I am a bit stumped as to how check for all 3. I tried the following which does not work.

```
string domainName = Request.Url.Host.ToString();
    if (domainName == "http://nomorecocktails.com" | Request.Url.Host.Contains("default.aspx"))

    { //code to push user control to page
```

Also tried

```
var url = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) + "/";
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: I don't understand. Where is this code running? Can't you just put the control ON the 'main page' - default.aspx or whatever?

Comment: Why is your markup shared between your homepage and your sub-pages? If you only want a user control to display on the homepage, you should have a separate ASPX page for it which is separate from the other pages. The solution you've come up with (checking the URL of the current page) is a hack around your design flaw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check if the `Request.Path` property is equal to `/` or `/Default.aspx` or whatever your "main page" is. The domain name is completely irrelevant. What if I accessed your site via `http://192.56.17.205/`, and similarly, what if your server switched IP addresses? Your domain check would fail.

If you utilize the QueryString to display different content, you'll also need to check `Request.QueryString`.

Documentation for `Request.Path`:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.path.aspx

Documentation for `Request.QueryString`:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.querystring.aspx

Comment: +1 ... and treating as an [Uri](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txt7706a) will make easier to handle independently from scheme, protocol, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the user control to only appear on the main page (I'm assuming you mean home page), then add the code to call the user control to the code behind of that file.

If this code is stored in the master page, then you can reference it like:

```
Master.FindControl("UserControlID");
```

---

If you are only using the one web form (ie. just `Default.aspx`), then you can check that no relevant query strings are included in the URL, and display only if this is the case:

```
if (Request.QueryString["q"] == null){
  //user control code
}
```

However if you are using this technique then I would recommend using multiple web forms using master pages in the future to structure your application better.

The ASP.NET website has some good tutorials on how to do this:

http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/master-pages

Comment: It sounds like his main page drives more than just the homepage (think `Default.aspx?q=/products/4`), so this won't work.

Comment: @SpikeX Thanks I've edited my post to provide an alternative solution.

Comment: Thanks everyone. The app I am using I did not design. The master page is used to create additional pages and content is pushed in via user controls.